# Shell script help on finding and replacing strings

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a config file as hive-site.xml

One configuration element is;

```
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.embedded.local.mode</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

I want to change the "true" to "false" by a shell script.
But in the file there are lots of configuration elements such as;

```
   <value>true</value>
```

tags.

So the "sed" command I used to find and replace strings is difficult to be used here with my knowledge. Appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: I suggest you use a Proper Programming Language with an XML parsing library.

Comment: So are you saying it is impossible to do this with a shell script ?

Comment: Not impossible, but very very difficult. (I would have serious trouble parsing XML in a shell script.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a job for XPath and a reasonable XML library. Doing this from a shell script directly is going to create a complicated and likely fragile solution. I'm going to use `python` and the popular `lxml` library as an example:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring('''
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.embedded.local.mode</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
''')

e = tree.xpath('//property[name="hadoop.embedded.local.mode"]/value')[0]
e.text = 'false'
print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Basically that selects any property node (anywhere in the doc) if it contains a `<name>` element with that value, then it selects the value element. You can then modify the element's content to your liking and print as a string again. XPath is standard, so roughly the same code ought to work in other implementations as well.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously quite a few ways to do this, but why not try awk (gawk)?

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk \
'        
    BEGIN {
        FLAG = 0;
    }

    /hadoop.embedded.local.mode/ {
        FLAG = 1;
    }

    />[     ]*true[     ]*</ {
        if (FLAG == 1) {
            FLAG = 0
            gsub("true", "false")
        }
    }

    {
        print
    }
' "$@"
```

Invoke the above script as:

```
<script> hive-site.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the whole block and change.

```
sed -i '/s/<property><name>hadoop.embedded.local.mode<\/name><value>true<\/value<\/property>
/<property><name>hadoop.embedded.local.mode<\/name><value>false<\/value><\/property>/' 
hive-site.xml
```

Comment: You need to escape the embedded slashes, or use a different delimiter. And do multi-line replacements really work? I thought sed operated a line at a time.

Comment: yes correct we need to escape slashes and multi-line replacements worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If the value you want to change is always on the next line you can first get the line number of the desired element with

```
NUMBER=$(grep -n "<desired element>" filename | awk -F: '{print $1}')
```

Then increment to the next line

```
let NUMBER="NUMBER + 1"
```

Then use sed or ex to modify the value, I prefer ex in these cases, as it eliminates the need for an interim text file.

```
{
print "${NUMBER}s/true/false/"
print "wq"
} | ex filename
```

Answer (score 0):

sed javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL

new_val="Chandu_jdbc"
sudo sed -i "/javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL/!b;n;c${new_val}" /tmp/hive-site.xml
sudo sed -i '/javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL/!b;n;c'${new_val}' /tmp/hive-site.xml
sudo sed -i "/javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL/!b;n;c${new_val}" /tmp/hive-site.xml
sudo sed -i '/javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL/!b;n;c'"${new_val}"'' /tmp/hive-site.xml

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).